# store javascript popup box input in array and display in alphabetic order

Tags: javascript

Take the names as input from a prompt box. The prompt box should keep asking 
names till a checkbox on the pop which says prevent additional dialoge is 
checked. After that display the names in alphabetical order which were 
entered through prompt box.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  function myFunction() {
 while(true)
       {
   var person = prompt("Please enter your name");
    }  
   var i=0;
     while(i<person.length)
     {
     if (person[i] != null) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =person[i]
     }
    i++;
       }
     }
      </script>

    </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

> <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html>
>   <body>
>   <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>
>   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
>   <p id="demo"></p>
>   <script>
>   var count=-1;
>   function myFunction() {
>   var person_names=new Array();
>   do{
>   count++;
>   person_names[count]= prompt("Please enter your name", "Naeem");
>   var i=0;
>   var person_names_list="";
>   if(person_names[count]==null || person_names[count]=="" || person_names[count]=='')
>   {
>   break;
>   }
>   }while(person_names[count]!= null);
>   person_names.reverse();
>   while(i<=count)
>   {
>   person_names_list=person_names_list+'
> '+person_names[i];
>   i++;
>   }
>   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =person_names_list+"";
>   }
>   </script>
>   </body>
>   </html>

**this will print the reverse order of the Array you take from user in dialog box thanks**

Comment: you can use **person_names.sort()** function instead of **person_names.reverse();**

Comment: to get in Ascending alphabetical order of array

Comment: try it button is not responding anything on any browser

Comment: now it is working the < sign was not working in the while condition it was hidden due to the stack overflow privileges Now Check the Update one